# Subject agreement is / are

Tags: subjects

Which one is correct?

1- The first five questions of interview **are** related to ....

2- The first five questions of interview **is** related to ...

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Hi Mehdi, you may not be aware that this EL&U site is for "linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts", whereas your question is probably more suited to our other site [ell.se]. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). FWIW, Mehdi, what's the *subject* of the verb? That will tell you whether to use the singular or plural verb form. :-)

Answer (score 2):

"The first five *questions* [ of **the** interview ] *are* related to ..." is correct. The plural subject "first five questions" needs to agree with a verb with a plural number "are". It's easier to see if you remove the genitive "of the interview" . It may sound odd to you, if spoken, to have a singular noun "the interview" followed by a plural verb, but it's correct.